# relation between maximum types values

Tags: c++

In my application, I play with large numbers stored in `long int` variables. Sometimes, I have to multiply them. So I use `long long int` variables to store the result. Example :

```
long long int multiplication(long int a, long int b)
{
  long long int r = (long long int)a * (long long int)b;
  return r;
}
```

In order to manage the pre-conditions to assert, I dreamed that `sizeof(long long int) >= 2*sizeof(long int)` was always true, but it's not the case. It seems that the only guaranty I have is that `sizeof(long int) >= 4` and `sizeof(long long int) >= 8`, but there is no rules between them.

What is the best way to manage this kind of situation ?

Comment: Are you writing multiplatform code or you can do assumptions? Without more assumptions you can't put more constraints about sizes. In any case you may go to use `int32_t` and `int64_t`. They're just platform independent aliases for the _basic_ types.

Comment: Yes, this code is compiled under 3 kinds of linux, Windows 32 and 64 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue, it would seem, isn't so much the types themselves,
but the maximum values that you have to deal with.  On most 64
bit systems, both `long` and `long long` will be 64 bits, but if
your code is portable to 32 bit systems as well, you may have to
restrict the values in the `long` to 32 bits anyway.  In that
case, there's no problem, even if on some machines, `long` is 64
bits.  The real issue is what assumptions can you make (and what
can you validate) with regards to your input.

Comment: It seems a good approach I can apply on a large part of my code. I really don't want to restrict the user while the values he send me match the pre-conditions.

Comment: @Caduchon It's a general rule.  Obviously, each library is unique, but in general, you'll find that you will have to introduce constraints.  (How you enforce them, and report errors if you do enforce them, is another issue.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like, int32_t, int64_t in  [cstdint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Comment: I think an answer is welcome to **extend** a comment not to make it even shorter...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I think you're welcome to give suggestions how to improve the answer or post your own answer. As it is, this answer does solve the problem, even though it's a bit terse.

Comment: With this solution, the problem can now happen at the cast from `long int` to `int32_t`. But ok, the responsability is now for the user of the function.

Comment: @Caduchon In general, functions taking a numerical value are only valid for a specific range.  It's up to the user to ensure that there input is in that range (although an `assert` at the top of the function isn't a bad idea).

Comment: Using these is a bad idea.  All it means is that any conversion will occur (implicitly) on the user side.  Silently given the wrong value if the user's value doesn't fit.

Comment: @user2079303 I wrote a comment before this _answer_. Too short to be considered a decent answer (that's why I posted as comment). An answer even shorter doesn't _add_ any value to what has been said before (compare with Jame Kanze's where it's **explained**). Of course if it's a race to post an answer as fast as possible... (BTW here I don't even see _where_ int32_t and int64_t should be used and it makes difference).

Comment: `BTW here I don't even see where int32_t and int64_t should be used and it makes difference` ok, that seems like a suggestion for this answer. Let's notify @notbad so he may choose to improve it.